# Obtener hora en el año

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, datetime

Me gustaría que de una fecha (por ejemplo 2 de enero de 2019 a las 02:00 horas) obtener el indice de hora anual.
Es decir del ejemplo que el return sea = 26.

```
date = 020120190200 (ddmmaaaaHHMM)
def get-indice_hora(date):

     return indice_hora_anual = 26
```

Estoy usando la librería datetime y estoy seguro que se puede obtener de un forma automática. 
Gracias

Answer (score 2):

`datetime` puede restar fechas y devolverte como resultado objetos de tipo `timedelta`, los cuales te pueden reportar la cantidad de segundos de diferencia. Basta dividir por 3600 para tenerlo en horas.

Las fechas a restar serían en este caso la que recibe como parámetro, menos otra fecha construida tomando sólo el año, y poniendo a 1 el día y mes.

```
from datetime import datetime
def get_indice_hora(date):
    fecha = datetime.strptime(date, "%d%m%Y%H%M")
    fecha_inicio = datetime(fecha.year, 1, 1)
    delta = fecha - fecha_inicio
    return delta.total_seconds()/3600
```

Uso:

```
>>> date = "020120190200"
>>> get_indice_hora(date)
26.0
```